# EF7 under Linux (CoreCLR) + MSSQL = Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed

Tags: sql-server, linux, azure, dnx

I try to run EF7 under Ubuntu linux on DNX Core

I wrote simple console app. It runs. It works well but when I connect to my SQLServer or Azure SQL Server I got this error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
   at EF7.Model.MyDbContext..ctor()
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
ClientConnectionId:726a8eca-eef5-4d8e-a525-54bdb7c08d1e
```

If I search in Google about this error it show me manual about SQLServer settings. But I try to run this code on azure and have same results.
My connection string is

```
Server=tcp:{AzureSQLServer}.database.windows.net,1433;Database=students;User ID={user};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: I also ran into this issue. Try using the rc1 binaries, the rc2 pre binaries currently fail on Linux. Also, Azure doesn't support not connecting via SSL so you have no other option.